# passing search string to grep as a shell variable

Tags: bash, grep

I have to write a small bash script that determines if a string is valid for the bash variable naming rules. My script accepts the variable name as an argument. I am trying to pass that argument to the grep command with my regex but everything I tried, grep tries to open the value passed as a file.

```
I tried placing it after the command as such
grep "$regex" "$1"

and also tried passing it as redirected input, both with and without quotes
grep "$regex" <"$1"
```

and both times grep tries to open it as a file. Is there a way to pass a variable to the grep command?

Answer (score 8):

Both your examples interpret "$1" as a filename. To use a string, you can use

```
echo "$1" | grep "$regex"
```

or a bash specific "here string"

```
grep "$regex" <<< "$1"
```

You can also do it faster without grep with

```
[[ $1 =~ $regex ]]  # regex syntax may not be the same as grep's
```

or if you're just checking for a substring,

```
[[ $1 == *someword* ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bash builtin feature `=~` . Like this:

```
if [[ "$string" =~ $regex ]] ; then 
    echo "match"
else 
    echo "dont match"
fi
```